# PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, PARAMETER_NAME,

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm working on migration Spring Batch 5. I'm using Jave 17 and Spring Boot 3. I didn't have any issue on step and job. However, In spring batch 5 DefaultBatchConfigurer is removed. setting datasource is different. I tried to use  Spring Batch 5 migiration guide but I'm getting PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, PARAMETER_NAME,... error.

my Batchconf file is:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(JobRepo.class)
@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "batchDataSource", transactionManagerRef = "batchTransactionManager")
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("BatchConfig")
    DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    public static void main(String e []) throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(LoadController.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(context.getBean(Job.class), jobParameters);
        System.out.println("Job Exit Status : " + jobExecution.getStatus());
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(5, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .processor(new CSVItemProcessor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JobBuilder("job")
                .start(step(jobRepository, transactionManager))
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.csv"))
                .name("personItemWriter")
                .delimited()
                .names("id", "name")
                .build();
    }



}
```

this is How I used datasource before spring batch 5 migration

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(JobRepo.class)
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DefaultBatchConfiguration dataSource(@Qualifier("BatchConfig") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }

    //step

   //job

   ...



}
```

JobRepo class is where I'm loading the db USERNAME, PASSWORD....

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public class JobRepo extends HikariConfig{

  @Bean("BatchConfig")
  public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException{

   return new HikariDataSource(this);
  }

}
```

this is my job luncher class

```
@Configuration
public class BatchUtil{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("BatchConfig")
    DataSource dataSource;
  
    private JobRepository getJobRep() throws Exception {
      JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
      factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
      factory.setTransactionManager(new ResourcelessTransactionManager());
      factory.afterPropertiesSet();
      return (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
      }

    @Bean("JobLauncher")
    public SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher () throws Exception {
      SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
      jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRep());
      jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor());
      return jobLauncher;
    }

}
```

Application.property

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1527:OR_DEV
spring.datasource.username=USER12
spring.datasource.password=txz$2Zhr
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

I tried to follow the spring batch 5 migration guide but it doesn't have an example.